# GitHub Action Repository Secrets & how to secure client_payload repo dispatch event Azure Container Registry

Tags: security, curl, github-api, github-actions, azure-acr

**Is there a way to pass data securely from between repos using the `client_payload` in a repository dispatch event?**

I [create a repository dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) for a CI pipeline I have between my two of my repos. My first repo uses Terraform in a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) to create Azure cloud resources and then is suppose to take the outputs for the sever address, username, and password of my container registry resource created using my `azure.tf` script.

In the final step of my GitHub Action in the first repo, it makes a POST request `curl` to notify my second repo that the initial cloud resources for the Azure Container Registry (ACR) have been created. It should now be safe to build my container images from my second repo and push them to ACR.

My problem is with the `client_payload` being sent over to my second repo, it is using unsecure raw json that will expose the password most importantly and other information in the output string of my running CI jobs under the GitHub action in my second repo.

This is why I'd like to understand if there's a way to pass data securely from between repos using the `client_payload`?

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/ME_SECOND_REPO_WITH_THE_CONTAINERS/dispatches' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
--header 'Authorization: token <MY_PAT>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "event_type": "MY_EVENT_TYPE",
  "client_payload": {
    "login_server": "UNSECURE_VALUE",
    "username": "UNSECURE_VALUE",
    "password": "UNSECURE_VALUE"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Organization Secrets

Github Action recently launched something called [organization secrets](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-05-14-organization-secrets/). That would be a better way to handle the service account credentials (assuming you are using service accounts).

## Manually trigger workflow

If you don't have service account setup, then the most recent [`workflow_dispatch` offering](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/) might be a better fit.

Workflow

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'     
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
```

Trigger screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Modified workflow would be like

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      login_server:
        description: 'login server'     
        required: true
        default: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
      username:
        description: 'username'  
        required: true
      password:
        description: 'password'  
        required: true
```

And you can use access them as

- `${{github.event.inputs.login_server}}`
- `${{github.event.inputs.username}}`
- `${{github.event.inputs.password}}`

**EDIT: To enable some level of Obfuscating**

[Masking a value in log](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#masking-a-value-in-log)

Comment: Is there way to create these secrets using code in the GitHub action or they can only be manually created? I'm using secrets in both of my repos currently, but the container server address and credentials will change each time I run the Terraform job.

Comment: Yeah, currently there is no API support for the Github secrets. (I hope they can fill this gap soon)

Comment: version control the secrets is big challenge for us as well.

Comment: @greg, i have updated my answer to include a better approach, let me know if that works.

Comment: this approach appears to work for me. i also add another layer of obfuscation by placing these event inputs into env variables in my action. in my case i am using `github.event.client_payload.my_var` since it's a `repository_dispatch` event.

Comment: how did you do the `obfuscation`?

Comment: this may be another solution we can use. there's a way for the terraform github provider to manage secrets for github. i'll propose another edit to your accepted answer to show this https://wahlnetwork.com/2020/05/12/continuous-integration-with-github-actions-and-terraform/

Comment: Looks like you are trying to introduce the terraform resource to address the setup? Did see bunch of edit rejections though. XD

Comment: I am yes, Terraform is where the `login_server` and credentials is generated from. Was any feedback provided for why this was rejected?

Comment: i think it probably because i did intend to make it overly complicated. LOL

Comment: maybe worth a separate post on this.

Comment: I have also shared the details in GitHub too https://github.community/t/secure-github-action-inputs/122310/2